# Absolute black shadow takes forever to render with custom shadow catcher node

Tags: rendering, node-editor, render-layers

I am trying to render this scene without the objects so only the shadows and reflections remain. I have a custom nodeset that separates the shadows and the reflections which is why I don't use the new Shadow Catcher.

Problem is the circled area where there is absolute black takes forever to render and I was wondering if there is a way to get past it.

Thanks!

[image][image]

Comment: Please don't add 'fixed' to the title. If you have a solution please post it as an answer instead of editing your question.

Comment: Yeah sure. I don't really use this website so I am unfamiliar with the 'Stack Exchange Etiquette'.

Comment: You need to [mark your answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235) too.

Comment: I need to wait two days (For some god knows reason)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the issue with this node set. Basically it says "just don't render this area if camera rays hit it" or something like that. I don't know I am bad at answering questions but if you have the same issue, try replicating this nodeset and maybe it will help you. It helped in my situation at least. [image]